# Invert polarity of seismic signal using obspy

Tags: python, signal-processing, obspy

One of the signal sensors reads the in inverted polarity of a signal, meaning it flips it. I am trying to invert it in python using Obspy.

Anyone can help me figure out how?

Answer (score 0):

figured it out!

I was trying to read in data from USGS using a station that is different from the rest of the stations I was using.

I was using a stream instead of a trace. To get the trace, I used tr=st[0] where st is the stream data I read using get_waveform. Then, I used this syntax
tr=st[0]
obspy.realtime.signal.scale(trace=tr,factor=-1,rtmemory_list=None)